# string_split into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

Sorry if this question is very basic, but I just can't figure it out, and couldn't find any good answers.

I have a very long list of files, folders and Sizes. I need to Seperate the folders to columns, that I have a column for each folder.

I have a FilePath as a String (eg folder1\folder2\folder3).
I want to seperate this into multiple Columns:

```
 First  |  Second  |  Third  |  Fourth  |  ...
folder1 | folder2  | folder3 | NULL     | ...
Foldera | folde rb  | folderc | folderd  |
```

using cross apply string_split(PATH,'\')as folder 
I get Folder1. 
using row_Number() I can define wich folder I have in my column, but it is always only 1 column.

Actual Example:

```
select [Parentpath], [Size], [spl].[value] from Files
cross apply string_split([ParentPath], '\') as [spl]


Parentpath                      || Size   ||  Value
Business\Packets\Data\Archive   || 29334  || Business
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also not pretty, but it allows for as\many\sub\folders\as\you\may\have.

```
-- borrowing from Brent:
CREATE TABLE #Files (Parentpath varchar(100), Size int);

INSERT INTO #Files (Parentpath, Size)
  VALUES ('Business\Packets\Data\Archive', 29334),
  ('Coach\Loss\Wharf\Current\Blat\Splunge\More', 7337);

DECLARE @s char(1) = CHAR(92), @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ParentPath, Size';

SELECT ParentPath, Size, value, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY ParentPath ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value + @s, ParentPath + @s))
  INTO #x FROM #Files AS f CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f.ParentPath, @s) AS t;

DECLARE @max int = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM #x);

SELECT @sql += N',  Folder' + RTRIM(rn) + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' 
            +  RTRIM(rn) + N' THEN value END)' 
  FROM (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) FROM sys.all_columns) AS x
  WHERE rn <= @max;

SET @sql += N' FROM #x GROUP BY ParentPath, Size ORDER BY Folder1' 
         +  CASE WHEN @max > 1 THEN N', Folder2' ELSE N'' END + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE #x, #Files;
```

With this sample data I get the following results:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution, although I am not sure, this is the best way to do it, but certainly sure, this is not the prettiest way to do it.

```
select x1.value as MainFolder, x2.value as SubFolder, x3.value as [secondSubFolder]
from Files f 
cross apply (
select xx.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by f.ParentPath order by f.ParentPath) AS PP
from string_split (f.ParentPath,'\') as xx
) as x1
cross apply (
select xx2.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by f.ParentPath order by f.ParentPath) as PP2
from string_split (f.ParentPath,'\') as xx2
) as x2
cross apply (
select xx3.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by f.ParentPath order by f.ParentPath) as PP3
from string_split (f.ParentPath,'\') as xx3
) as x3
where PP = 1
and PP2 = 2
and pp3 = 3
group by x1.value, x2.value, x3.value
order by MainFolder asc, SubFolder asc
```

is giving me :
[image]

I left out the Size, as I was interested in dividing the Path into seperate folders first.

Edit: 
Sorry, this Screenshot is different to the question, due to sorting the results. 
To clarify: 
ParentPath to the displayed result would be:
    "Business Intelligence\GLS Paketdaten \ GLS Daten Archiv"

Or as a Table with posted content:

```
MainFolder      |  SubFolder   |  secondSubfolder
Business        |   Packets    |      Data
```

P.S Sorry, English is not my first language. I hope I wrote it understandable.